# Drupal 7: Browser not displaying draggable-handles

Tags: firefox, drupal-7, draggable, hidden, displaytag

Ok; I'm stumped on this one. This regards the built-in draggable sort functionality you use for basic blocks or organizing books. I'm using the latest Firefox on Fedora 20. I also use profiles, meaning different instances of Firefox with separate caches and add-ons. However, in both profiles, I am logging into my Drupal site with the same credentials.

**The Problem:** For the last few days my primary browser has suddenly stopped showing the draggable handles in any primary Firefox profile. Inspection of the code shows that they are receiving a "display: none" element style in every case. However, this is happening only in one of my Firefox profiles. If I could even duplicate the problem in my other profile I'd have some clues, but I can't get them to disappear there any more than I can get them to come back in my primary. Remember, I'm logged into my Drupal site as the same user in either case, so it shouldn't be a permissions thing.

Things I've tried so far:

- disabling all add-ons
- Clearing all memory and caches. Again, and again, in conjunction with everything else I've tried
- Clearing all Drupal caches
- Force-refreshing the pages (shift+r)

You can see the problem here; it's not even a stylesheet thing, but something effecting generation of the drag-handle elements to apply a "display:none" to them.

See my firebug comparison screens attached.

**EDIT** I "cloned" my profile by creating a new Firefox profile and syncing everything (addons, history, etc); the new profile does NOT have the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After clearing my cookies (a separate operation from all the cache clearing), it was fixed. I am still perplexed by why there should be a cookie with the power to toggle draggable blocks, but there we have it.

**Solution: Clear Cookies**